# SQL query not working in TableAdapter Query Configuration wizard for VB.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, dataset, tableadapter

I have a query that works fine in `MySQL Workbench`but it doesn't when I try to use it in the `TableAdapter Query Configuration wizard`.

The query is a simple `Select` with a subquery in it:

```
SELECT a,b,(SELECT c,d FROM ... WHERE) FROM ... WHERE...
```

Is there something I need to change in the query to make it work in the configuration wizard ?

Comment: I know this post is old, but did you find an answer? I am having the exact same issue, query with subquery runs fine in MySQL Workbench but fails in the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard. **One thing I noticed is that I get this error when trying to use a MySQL database. Running the same query in the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard against a SQL Server database works just fine.** I am using Visual Studio 2015, MySQL 5.7, and SQL Server Express 2016 and following this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx#aspnet_tutorial01_dataaccesslayer_vb_topic6
Step

Comment: I did not. In my case I needed the table adapter to create a RDLC report so I ended up creating a DataTable and then used Dapper to do the same query. TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard with MySQL is very shady, sometimes it works...sometimes it doesn't.